# Nonlinear 2nd-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am stuck with the following ODE. New to ODEs, it's kind of hard for me to solve it. Any analytical solution would be grat. Kindly help.

$\frac{d}{dx}(y^\frac{-1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}y)+\frac{2}{3}\frac{d}{dx}y^\frac{3}{2}+(y^\frac{-3}{2}-y^\frac{1}{2})$=0,

The BCs are $y(\infty)=1, \frac{d}{dx}y(\infty)=0.$

Comment: Is $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} y^{3/2}=$ $(y’)^{3/2}$ or $(y^{3/2})’$?

Comment: It is the second one.

Comment: Taking $y(x)=u(x)^2$, then $u(x)’=p(u)$ you’ll arrive at an Abel equation, which you’ll be hard pressed to get an analytical solution for.

Comment: Equation’s reduced, and let me try with the solution